# Accessing Axapta report fields

Tags: axapta, x++

I want to iterate over the fields of an Axapta report.
The problem I am facing is that I want to turn the fields visible and invisible before the report is shown. So I am overriding the Display method and add checkboxes to the Dialog.

I am looking for something that I can iterate over, like this

**pseudocode:**

```
public Object dialog(Object _dialog)
{
    ListIterator it;
    Dialog dialog;
    ;
    it = new ListIterator (this.fields); 
    dialog = super(_dialog);
    while (it.more())
    {
        dialog.addField(typeId(NoYesId),it.value);
        it.next();
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

How can I access the fields of a report ?

**Further information:**

I am using Dynamics Ax 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10381595/4509).

To access a report field, set the fields `AutoDeclaration` to Yes. Then the field is open for whatever:

```
stringControl.visible(...);
```

See report `tutorial_FontInfo` for an example of locating the control by name.

All controls of a report section can be accessed by number:

```
for (i = 1; i <= reportSection.controlCount); i++)
{
    rc = reportSection.controlNo(i);   
}
```

Comment: It may sound stupid but where do i find "tutorial_FontInfo" ?

Comment: On the reports node the AOT. In AX 2009, if not in AX 4.0 look at the other tutorial reports.